# CLI/Testing: Language for testing command line interfaces

Tags: testing, command-line-interface

What is the best (probably, scripting) language for testing command line interfaces (CLI) ?
I tried [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), but it is not object oriented and therefore it is not too convenient for testing multiple connections simultaneously. 
Tests should be run on Linux and Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having great success at using VBScript / JScript (via Windows Script Host) as a unit testing harness for both console applications and ActiveX COM objects. Then, the moment there are interactive elements, I scale to HTML Applications (via MSHTA).

Comment: VBScript is not sutable for testing from Linux. Another requirement is to support multiple connections. Example - imagine that you wand to test two connected networking devices (e.g. routers).

Answer (score 0):

Any modern portable  script languge is fine, you may take a look at [Outthentic](https://dev.to/melezhik/command-line-application-tests-made-easy-with-outthentic-j49) testing framework, it works both for windows and Linux platforms and designed to test cli applications. Using the framework, you can write your tests on the language of your choice - Perl, Python, Ruby, Bash.