# functional testing for vagrant puppet provisioning (or running a CLI test suite)

Tags: shell, testing, command-line-interface, vagrant, puppet

I'm looking for a way to automate functional testing of vagrant provisioning scripts (using puppet and shell scripts).  **please notice:** I'm asking about functional testing and not unittesting the puppet modules, the puppet catalog etc.

Is there a recommended way to do that? maybe something along python doctests: "with this input this should be the CLI output". Searched around but couldn't find a working example or a recommanded tool.

If there isn't any vagrant/puppet sanctioned solution for this, is there a simple **CLI testing**  tool? where I can make asserts about certain outputs vs certain inputs?

I saw [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076391/cli-testing-language-for-testing-command-line-interfaces) but it didn't really get a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [**serverspec**](http://serverspec.org/) would suite your needs. In particular, with the `command` resource type, which you can read about [here](http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#command), you should be able to do exactly what you've described.

Note that in addition you can use it to test other resources like processes or opened ports without having to deal with ad-hoc command line scripts.